# Flipping an enemy sprite when he turns around in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d, sprite, flip

I'm some hours already trying to solve this, I tried many ways but none of them worked...

So I have an enemy that follows the player using an AI and I need the sprite to flip when the enemy turn left or turn right.

Here's a part of my code (A lot of the code is about the AI so I'll post just part of it)

```
Vector3 dir = ( path.vectorPath[currentWaypoint] - transform.position ).normalized;
dir *= speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime;

//Move the AI
rb.AddForce (dir, fMode);

void Update () {

    if (rb.AddForce > 0) {
        sr.flipX = false;
    } else if (rb.AddForce < 0)
        sr.flipX = true;

    animate.SetFloat ("pMove", Mathf.Abs(rb.AddForce));   
}
```

Comment: `rb.AddForce > 0` ??  First of all, `AddForce` is a function and is also a `void` return type. I really encourage you understand [basic C# stuff](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/s/scripting) before you continue.

Comment: It's more efficient to have pre-rendered sprites for all orientations (unless your game supports more than say 8 directions) than to use some trickery

Comment: @Programmer Well I kinda knew that but as I said, I tried many ways and this way just was the last one, I was at least checking, who knows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to flip a sprite is using `localScale.x *= -1;` And instead of checking the AddForce you should check the velocity of the rigidbody in the x axis (or y axis if you flip as well the sprite depending on if it is jumping or falling)

Basically in `Update()` you can do something like this: `vx = rigidbody.velocity.x;` to store the velocity in the x axis of the sprite. Then in `LastUpdate()` you check if it is necessary to flip the sprite or not:

```
if (vx > 0) {
    facingRight = true;
} else if (vx < 0) { 
    facingRight = false;
}

if (((facingRight) && (localScale.x<0)) || ((!facingRight) && (localScale.x>0))) {
    localScale.x *= -1;
}
```

Here you have a whole example where the sprite moves based on the player's inputs. You will need to addapt it for your AI.

```
//store references to components on the gameObject
Transform transform;
Rigidbody2D rigidbody;

public float MoveSpeed = 3f;

// hold player motion in this timestep
float vx;
float vy;

Awake () {
    // get a reference to the components we are going to be changing and store a reference for efficiency purposes
    transform = GetComponent<Transform> ();
    rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ();

}


void Update()
{
    // determine horizontal velocity change based on the horizontal input
    vx = Input.GetAxisRaw ("Horizontal");

    //Change in case you are jumping or falling
    vy = rigidbody.velocity.y;

    // Change the actual velocity on the rigidbody
    rigidbody.velocity = new Vector2(_vx * MoveSpeed, _vy);

}

// Checking to see if the sprite should be flipped
// this is done in LateUpdate since the Animator may override the localScale
// this code will flip the player even if the animator is controlling scale
void LateUpdate()
{
    // get the current scale
    Vector3 localScale = transform.localScale;

    if (vx > 0) // moving right so face right
    {
        facingRight = true;
    } else if (vx < 0) { // moving left so face left
        facingRight = false;
    }

    // check to see if scale x is right for the player
    // if not, multiple by -1 which is an easy way to flip a sprite
    if (((facingRight) && (localScale.x<0)) || ((!facingRight) && (localScale.x>0))) {
        localScale.x *= -1;
    }   

    // update the scale
    transform.localScale = localScale;
}
```

Comment: This is a neat approach, just as setting the Y-rotation to 180 degrees. However, I was wondering if, in this particular case, modifying a `Rigidbody`'s `Transform` would force physics to re-calculate the colliders for the `GameObject`. What happens to the forces in the X-direction when the scale is -1? I am asking because Unity documentation for `Rigidbody` explicitly stresses that ["you shouldn’t manipulate the Rigidbody and the Transform of the same GameObject - only one or the other"](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Rigidbody.html), because `Rigidbody` has torques and forces on it.

Comment: I will read about this link later and I will let you know. But so far I didnt have problems with this approach.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try this one right now, I was sleeping :p

Comment: @Caick ok, let me know if something is not clear, I will try to explain in more detail.

Comment: @SerkanPekçetin Ok I checked that link. First the one you passed is about 3D, so I refer to the 2D equivalent and they also have a similar sentence: "The Rigidbody 2D component overrides the Transform and updates it to a position/rotation defined by the Rigidbody 2D. Note that while you can still override the Rigidbody 2D by modifying the Transform component yourself, doing so will cause problems such as GameObjects passing through or into each other, and unpredictable movement." As I understand the problems happens when you use the transform to change the position of the GameObject

Comment: @SerkanPekçetin ...but in my case what I modify is the scale to make the mirror effect. So it should not cause problems when detecting colisions. However if you still have other potential bugs in mind, let me know and I will investigate. I kind of like this sort of researches haha

Comment: Omg yes It worked! thanks so much. Now I'll study more to know enough to help other people.

Comment: Bad idea if you want your sprites to batch together.. negative scale breaks batching. Would not recommend, use SpriteRenderer flipX instead it's made for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming, `sr` is a `SpriteRenderer` component, `sr.flipX` approach is fine. However, your assessment of the force on the `Rigidbody` is not right. `rb.AddForce` has the return type of `void`, and a proper way of reading whether the `Rigidbody` had an applied force on it is to read `rb.velocity.magnitude`. Also, `rb.velocity` would give you the direction of the GameObject's velocity as a `Vector3`. Assuming that you are working on the X-axis, putting this in your `LateUpdate` method:

```
sr.flipX = rb.velocity.magnitude > 0 && rb.velocity.x < 0 ? true : false;
```

instead of the if-else block at your `Update` method would flip the sprite along the X-axis if the `Rigidbody` is moving (`rb.velocity.magnitude > 0`) and it is moving towards the left-hand side (`rb.velocity.x < 0`).

In your question, you have asked only to flip the sprite: As [Unity documentation states](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/SpriteRenderer-flipX.html), `flipX` only affects rendering, not the other components (such as colliders and animators).